# Unique validation error in many to many relations

Tags: django, validation, many-to-many, django-rest-framework, unique

I have a serializer with an unique `name` field :

```
class ProductTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.URLField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    name = serializers.CharField(validators=[
        UniqueValidator(queryset=ProductType.objects.all())
    ])
    user =  UserSerializer(required=False)
    publish = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductType
        fields = ('url',
                  'id',
                  'name',
                  'publish',
                  'user',
                  'register_date')
```

On the other hand, there is another serializer with a many-to-many relation to the serializer with unique name field :

```
class BrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.URLField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    name = serializers.CharField()
    product_types = ProductTypeSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    user = UserSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = ('url',
                  'id',
                  'name',
                  'product_types',
                  'publish',
                  'user',
                  'register_date')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print  'validated_data:', validated_data
        request = self.context['request']
        name = validated_data.get('name', None)
        publish = validated_data.get('publish', False)
        product_types_data = validated_data.pop('product_types', None)
        product_types = []
        for pt in product_types_data:
            product_type = ProductType.objects.get(pk=pt['id'])
            product_types.append(product_type)
        obj = Brand.objects.create(
            name=name,
            publish=publish,
            user=request.user
           )
        obj.product_types.add(*product_types)
    return obj
```

I get an unique validation error when I post brand data with the `BrandSerializer`:

```
{"product_types":[{"name":["This field must be unique."]}]}
```

How to suppress the validation of `ProductTypeSerializer` when we create a brand with `BrandSerializer`?

Comment: What does BrandSerializer.create look like? It looks like you try to create a new ProductType instead of assigning an existing one.

Comment: @Linovia these are not same questions. my ask has unique validation in serializer field and i used many-to-many relations . be careful :|

Comment: @TomasWalch Ask is updated now. i just get product_types in `create` method :o

Comment: @TomasWalch , the `create` method is not called at all. the unique validation for the `productType` occures before of runing `create` method

Comment: @irajjelodari are you sure that your product type name is not duplicated ?

Comment: @Linovia are you sure to comprehention of my previous comment? if you say yeah, it is good and hopefully

Comment: @irajjelodari I do not see how this question differs from the one linked. Words are different, issue is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `product_type` field as `read_only` field and to create it, get data from `request.data` not `validated data`

```
class BrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.URLField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    name = serializers.CharField()
    product_types = ProductTypeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    user = UserSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = ('url',
                  'id',
                  'name',
                  'product_types',
                  'publish',
                  'user',
                  'register_date')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print  'validated_data:', validated_data
        request = self.context['request']
        name = validated_data.get('name', None)
        publish = validated_data.get('publish', False)
        product_types_data = request.data.get('product_types', None)
        product_types = []
        for pt in product_types_data:
            product_type = ProductType.objects.get(pk=pt['id'])
            product_types.append(product_type)
        obj = Brand.objects.create(
            name=name,
            publish=publish,
            user=request.user
           )
        obj.product_types.add(*product_types)
    return obj
```

And if you want to validate if product_type was passed as parameter in the request, you can do it on the `clean` method

Comment: Do not use request.data with DRF. By doing this, you're just bypassing any validation.

Comment: @Linovia you perfectly validate it using serializer clean method if you want to.